# Macro not working when i have two conditions

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to create a tracker that when "closed on time" or "Closed late" is chosen from a drop down, it automatically hides the entire row. I am currently using the below code, Closed late works but not the closed on time. Can anyone help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    BeginRow = 3
    EndRow = 700
    ChkCol = 14

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If (Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol)(.Value = "Closed late")) And (.Value = "Closed on time") Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next RowCnt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that

```
If (Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol)(.Value = "Closed late")) And (.Value = "Closed on time") Then
```

is no valid syntax. It should be

```
If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "Closed late" And Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "Closed on time") Then
```

Nevertheless I recommend the following improvements:

With `Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range(Cells(BeginRow, ChkCol), Cells(EndRow, ChkCol)))` you can make sure your code runs only on the changed cells in column 14. So you don't loop through unnecessary non-changed cells.

Also I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim BeginRow As Long
    BeginRow = 3

    Dim ChkCol As Long
    ChkCol = 14

    Dim EndRow As Long
    EndRow = 700 'could be replaced with dynamic solution below
    'EndRow = Target.Parent.Cells(Target.Parent.Rows.Count, ChkCol).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim ChangedCells As Range
    Set ChangedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range(Cells(BeginRow, ChkCol), Cells(EndRow, ChkCol)))

    If Not ChangedCells Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In ChangedCells
            If Cell.Value = "Closed late" Or _
               Cell.Value = "Closed on time" Then
                Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Works perfectly. Great help!